# GraphQL: Validating array elements are in list

Tags: ruby, graphql

I have the following argument in my Ruby GQL:

```rb
argument :countryCode, [String], required: false, validates: {inclusion: {in: COUNTRY_CODES}}, prepare: :strip
```

What I want this to achieve is to allow an array of Strings to be used, and each value in the array to be one of `COUNTRY_CODES`

However, this returns the exception "is not included in the list".  What is wrong here?

Comment: first argument name must be in lower_case symbol :country_code

Comment: second https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/2.0.7/GraphQL/Schema/Validator/InclusionValidator seems like can't validate array in array https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/lib/graphql/schema/validator/inclusion_validator.rb#L28

Answer (score 0):

Better way for this case create enum with countries, but in this case client must send enum hardcoded country code, other way use validator like dry-validation of similar